# Multiple table queries using Codeingiter active record does not give intended result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am storing number of rows returned from querying multiple tables, in a single Model function using Codeigniter Active Record Class, my model function looks like -

Model -

```
function my_model_function($param1)
{
     $step_passed = array();

        $step_passed['step1'] = 'pass'; 

       $query_table1 = $this->db->where('param1', $param1)
                                         ->get('table1');   

       if($query_table1->num_rows() > 0)
       {
        $step_passed['step2'] = 'pass';
       }

       $query_table2 = $this->db->where('param1', $param1)
                                    ->get('table2'); 
      if($query_table2->num_rows()> 0)
      {
          $step_passed['step3'] == 'pass';
      }

      return $step_passed;
}
```

In my view as when I print_r this result -

```
Array([step1] => pass [step2] => pass)
```

However my expected result should be like -

```
Array([step1] => pass [step2] => pass [step3] => pass)
```

I confirm that the all tables[table1, table2, table3] have data matching param1  but I dont see table 3 result.

What I've tried -

```
 1.I tried printing the number of rows returned from query_table2 and
    it comes as 1 which is greater than 0, and I have no idea why my if    statement is not lighting up at this point
  2. I tried entering test key value pair inside my mode function like -

$step_passed['test_data'] = 'test';
```

and I see the result as -

```
Array([step1] => pass [step2] => pass [test] => test)
```

I having difficulty getting inside my if($query_table2->num_rows()> 0) statement which really returns 1, Can you please help me resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Siva

You have written

`$step_passed['step3'] == 'pass';`

And here you have used `==` operator, so please replace it with `'='`. So it should be like below

`$step_passed['step3'] = 'pass';`

Comment: Guess, this means I need to sleep early tonight, I might've been seeing things, this is so embarrassing. Thank you for your reply !

Comment: Its okay siva :)